# Macro for a multi line C preprocessor directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, compiler-directives

I was trying to create a shorthand for the following code.

```
#ifdef   TEST_DEF  
#define  MY_TEST_DEF TEST_DEF 
#else
#define  MY_TEST_DEF 120 
#endif
```

How do I write the above code as a single line macro

```
SAFE_DEF(TEST_DEF,MY_TEST_DEF,120)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Every new define must be defined on its own line, and cannot declare a new define in itself.

You will have use the ifdef,else method.